# Add a single element at the specified index

Tags: java, arraylist

I'd love to exercise the CRUD principle in ArrayList in java
I started today by exercising the add method however I get error
when I add the methode add in static main methode I get error that the add methode should be static
and when I put it static I get error by the arraylist and scanner as Strange element even wenn I add those the the static add methode After excuting the ide I get error " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0"  could someone explain me why is so

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

        add();
        System.out.println(arrayList1);
    }

    public static void add(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

        int index=scanner.nextInt();
        String element=scanner.next();
        arrayList1.add(index,element);

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: In the second line of the method `add` you initialize the List with a size of 0 (empty). Therefore you can only add the first element to the index `0`. Given from the error-message your input was 2.

Comment: input 2  java I want to add the keyword java in the third possition of the array and the first und second elements should be automaticly intitilazed with 0 is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply: You can't just add an element at a certain index (that isn't the 0th) in an uninitialized list. When you call your add function the array list is empty, which is why you're getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: does it mean I have to initialize it first?if yes how please

Comment: Yes, you cannot add an element with an index that does not exist in a list. If a list has a size of 4 you cannot add an element at an index greater the size of the list. Ex: [0, 1, 2, 3], you cannot add element 5 at index 5 without having an element at index  4 first. To initialize a list, it's pretty trivial just something like this:  `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add("hello");
arr.add("hey");
arr.add("hi");`

Comment: I intilazed the arraylsist withe ``static List<String> arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(new String[10]);`` my input was  2 java  and got the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
 at com.company.Main.add(Main.java:22)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: Again, it's not simply a matter of having the list initialized. You can't add an element at an index that is greater than the size of the list. In the example I showed you, the size was 4, so you cannot add an element with an index >= 5.

Comment: I initilazed the arraylist with 10 elements and when I wanted to add the keyword java in 2th postion I got the error

Comment: That's because in an Arrays.asList you cannot modify the size. In your case, you've declared it as a fixed size of 10 so you cant add any values to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a list, it is initially empty. You can't add an element to index 2 if there is no item at index 0. The ArrayList class does not create elements out of nowhere for the positions 0 and 1.

You can always add an element to the end of a list, or to the beginning of a list, even if the list is empty. These are always safe:

```
arrayList1.add(0, element); // Add to beginning of the list
arrayList1.add(element);    // Add to end of the list
```

Your program has some duplicate and unused variables. For example, `scanner` and `arrayList1` don't have to re-declared and initialized in every method - in fact, doing it will lead to bugs further down the line. You can make the class-level variables `static` and then you can use them in all methods:

```
class Main {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static List<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add();
        System.out.println(arrayList1);
    }

    public static void add() {
        int index = scanner.nextInt();
        String element = scanner.next();
        arrayList1.add(index, element);
    }
}
```

This is not the best way to program in Java, as you will learn when your  studies bring you to *object oriented concepts* but for a beginner this is good enough

Comment: I've already learn OOP concept but I don't know what' the relation between my code the OOP? could you explain me more, I 'd love the improve my programmation skill , I am stil looking for a tutor

Comment: Well there is no relation between your code and Object Oriented Programming. In OOP you would express the program in terms of meaningful *objects* that encapsulate state and communicate with each other. But your code does not really have objects: instead it uses just a low level "list of strings" data structure